How to train a seq2seq model for converting structured text?
I am trying to train a model to convert some old templates to jinja2.
{if $logged_in}
    Welcome, <font color="{#fontColor#}">{$name}!</font>
{else}
    hi, {$name}
{/if}

to
{% if context.logged_in %}
    Welcome, <font color="{{ fontColor }}">{{ context.name }}!</font>
{% else %}
    hi, {{ context.name }}
{% endif %}

I have narrowed down the methodology to seq2seq and written a small program referencing various blog posts and tutorials.
But I am facing trouble keeping the text sequence.
How do I train it such that, it only needs to worry about stuff inside {} and can just copy paste everything else as is?

Why can't you just search and replace?

@molbdnilo 1. Trying to make it a generic solution which will work with new templates as well. 2. Trying to get into AI/ML.

Can you explain more about the input and output of your dataset based on your current approach? Is the input sequence "{if $logged_in}" and the output sequence "{% if context.logged_in %}"? Or are you trying to convert the full template? Please add that information to the question.
